# How to write this SQL query as a JPA query

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have this query that is running successfully in mysql but I am trying to write it as a JPA query and I keep getting errors. Here are my tables.

```
Table 1: business_accounts{id, business_name}
Table 2: work_locations{location_id, name, contractor_id }
//contractor_id on Table2 is the foreign key matched to id on table 1.
```

My sql query is that I want to return all values of business_name where id from table 1 equals contractor_id from table 2 and where name="Dublin" Here is my sql query that is working in mysql:

```
SELECT b.business_name FROM work_locations w 
inner join business_accounts b on b.id=w.contractor_id where name="Carlow"
```

And here is the approach that I am taking in JPA that isn't working. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

```
    String countyName="Dublin";

        Query myQuery2 = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM business_accounts b join "
                + "w where b.id=w.contractor_id and w.name=:countyName");

        myQuery2.setParameter("countyName", countyName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to create correct entities corresponding to the table.
   a. Business_Account entity

b. Work_Location is the other

c. You may choose to create separate a separate join table for the join between a. and b. I would suggest that, but its your preference.

Based on the a. and b. Try something on these lines -

```
String countyName="Dublin";
final TypedQuery<String> query = entityManager
            .createQuery(
                    "Select distinct b.business_name from Business_Account b, IN(b.id) location where b.id=location and location.name =:countyName", String.class); //$NON-NLS-1$
    query.setParameter("countyName", countyName); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

1. Use `createNativeQuery`
2. SELECT b.business_name instead of SELECT b
3. Add the ENTITY CLASS with the query that will be the return type.

   ```
   String QUERY = "SELECT b.business_name FROM business_accounts b join w where b.id=w.contractor_id and w.name=?)";

   List list = em.createNativeQuery(QUERY, ENTITY_CLASS_HERE.class)
     .setParameter(1, countyName)
     .getResultList();
   ```